# Redux: How does redux differ from throwing the state on the window object?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a relatively small app and having been passing data up to the top level of my App so that they can be passed down to other areas of the app.  Is this essentially what Redux is doing ?

Comment: No, redux is like a "global" storage for components so you don't need to pass values to your root component and then back down another "tree".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In envision Redux more of like a parallel structure to your app components hierarchy. Then, when you bind components to redux you open a communication channel to modify state and receive just certain updates. Redux takes care of triggering the reprocessing/rendering of just the components affected by the state change.

On the other hand, if you manage state by sending data up/down your component hierarchy, all component structure gets new props(i am assuming you are using react), and all components get "reprocessed" unless you implemented "shouldComponentUpdate" method, which could impact your performace. You could see this if you override "componentWillReceiveProps" and console out each processing.

For a small application it could be easiest to use window object, but as your app grows it could be a problem for maintainability, and there is also other advantages of using redux like security.

Comment: what do you mean by reprocessed?

Comment: I mean that every time your component receives new props, a set of methods get executed to reflect the changes props may provoke in the component and sub components. All part of the component life cycle.